# Laravel Auth::user()->id returns null on livewire form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I'm try to get `Auth::user()->id` as my form value. It can shows on the label but it return value **null**.

[image]

View :

```
<option value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" data-keterangan="">{{ Auth::user()->id }}</option>
```

Http/Livewire :

```
        $this->validate([
            'customer_code'=>'required|string',
            'customer_name'=>'required|string',
            'phone_number'=>'required|string'
        ]);

        StokItem::updateOrCreate([
            'customer_code'=>$this->customer_code,
            'customer_name'=>$this->customer_name,
            'phone_number'=>$this->phone_number
        ]);
```

Model :

```
    protected $fillable = ['id','customer_code','customer_name','phone_number','produk_code','produk_name','produk_uom','qty','kode_kondisi_barang','jenis_kondisi_barang','remark','url_foto','status'];
```

Comment: If you inspect the option in the browser, can you see the value then or is it just ""?

Comment: in inspect it shows 
`<option value data-keterangan>1</option>`

Comment: why you don't use it in the controller, why pass It from view?

Comment: Hmm weird. You could try to store the result in a variable, and then printing that variable where it is needed. This would also increase the efficiency of the code. Try this: On any line in the view, do this: ``@php ($user_id = Auth::user()->id)``. Then print the variable where you want it. ``{{ $user_id }}``.

Comment: @MoussabKbeisy I'm new on laravel-livewire, it seems different case.

Comment: @EricQvarnström Thank you, I've tried it but it dodn't work for me :')

Comment: @PremanTerminal Okay, very weird.. Never experienced this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do `auth()->name()`, you need to call the authenticated user by doing `auth()->user()` then after that get the column you have in your database eg `auth()->user()->name`

(https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-auth)

In your `Livewire Component`, you should do something like this

```php
public $id = '';
public $name = '';     
public $no_hp = '';

public function mount()
{
   $this->id = auth()->id();         
   $this->name = auth()->user()->name;         
   $this->no_hp = auth()->user()->no_hp;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I got errors. Can you help me? 
My code : `public $id = '';
    public $name = '';
    public $no_hp = '';

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->id = auth()->id();
        $this->name = auth()->name();
        $this->no_hp = auth()->no_hp();
    }`

Error : 
`Undefined method 'name'`

Comment: Thankyou verymush @migsAV , it works!!! 
And note for myself don't forget to disable field from `public function resetFields()` , so my value don't return null when I send it to model.

Comment: Please note that a Livewire component should never overwrite any of the `$id`, `$name` or `$data` properties, as those properties are used internally by Livewire

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your user is authenticate

```
@auth
  <option value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" data-keterangan="">{{ Auth::user()->id }}</option>
@endauth
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it but it dodn't work for me :')